# odoo import models, fields, api ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo'

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I am new with working in odoo 11.0 and when i run my file hos.py this error will pop out (from odoo import models, fields, api, : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo' ).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM7xk.png)

Answer (score 1):

For developing your own odoo modules/modules you need to start odoo-bin to test them:
`odoo-bin`
You can find odoo-bin in the odoo project https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/11.0

Also if you are developing your own modules you need to add the modules/addons directory to the odoo.conf.

Odoo Modules are usually not executable outside of an odoo instance.

Have a look at the developer documentation for 11.0 here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at all your initialization **init**.py files,
change

```
import [module_name]
```

to

```
from . import [module_name]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).